# Export VCard from JS and open in contacts

Tags: javascript, vcf-vcard

I have been trying to figure this out for a little while now. I modified a javascript code to create a VCard. The script currently generates a QR code when the submit button is pressed. If I scan the code with my phone it opens up my contacts with everything filled out. What I want to do is bypass the QR code process and have the script open it automatically when the submit button is pressed. Is there an easy way to take this code and simply export it and open it instead of saving and generating a QR code?

Here's the button code.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Generate">
```

And here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vcard= {
    str_start:'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n',
    str_vcard:'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n',
    str_end:'\nEND:VCARD',
    goog_chart:'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=',
    form:[],
    get_field: function(field){
        for(var i in vcard.form){
            if(vcard.form[i].name === field){
                return vcard.form[i].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            }
        }
    },
    add_you: function(){
        var first_name = "MARC",
        last_name = "MATTEO",
        birthday = vcard.get_field('birthday'),
        gender = vcard.get_field('gender');

        vcard.str_vcard += 'N:'+last_name+';'+first_name+'\n'+
        'FN:'+first_name+' '+last_name;
        if(birthday !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nBDAY:'+birthday; }

        if(gender !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nX-GENDER:'+gender; }
    },
    add_address: function(){
        var
        org_street = "org_street",
        org_city = "org_city",
        org_region = "org_region",
        org_post = "org_post",
        org_country = "org_country";


        if(org_street+org_city+org_region+org_post+org_country !== ''){
            vcard.str_vcard += '\nADR;TYPE=work:;;'+org_street+';'+org_city+';'+org_region+
            ';'+org_post+';'+org_country;
        }
    },
    add_tel: function(){
        var
        work = "8005551212";
        if(work !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nTEL;TYPE=work:'+work; }
    },
    add_email: function(){
        var  work = "testemail@email.com";
         if(work !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nEMAIL;TYPE=internet,work:'+work; }
    },
    add_url: function(){
        var
        work = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
        if(work !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nURL;TYPE=work:'+work; }
    },
    add_work: function(){
        var name = "My Business Name",
        title = "CEO";
        if(name !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nORG:'+name; }
        if(title !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard +='\nTITLE:'+title; }
    },

    add_note: function(){
        var name = "My custom note can be anything";
        if(name !== ''){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nNOTE:'+name; }
    },


    add_social: function(){
        var facebook = "https://www.facebook.com/myaccount",
        twitter = "https://www.twitter.com/testaccount",
        instagram = "https://www.instagram.com/marcanthonyphoto",
        linkedin = "https://www.linkedin.com/marcanthonyphoto";

        if(facebook !== 'https://www.facebook.com/'){ vcard.str_vcard += '\nX-SOCIALPROFILE;type=facebook:'+facebook; }

        if(twitter !== 'https://www.twitter.com/'){ vcard.str_vcard +='\nX-SOCIALPROFILE;type=twitter:'+twitter; }

        if(instagram !== 'https://www.instagram.com/'){ vcard.str_vcard +='\nX-SOCIALPROFILE;type=Instagram:'+ instagram; }

        if(linkedin !== 'https://www.linkedin.com/'){vcard.str_vcard +='\nX-SOCIALPROFILE;type=linkedin:'+ 'https://www.linkedin.com/marcanthonyphoto';}

    },

    save: function(){
        vcard.form = $('form').serializeArray();

        vcard.add_you();

        vcard.add_address();

        vcard.add_tel();

        vcard.add_email();

        vcard.add_url();

        vcard.add_work();

        vcard.add_note();

        vcard.add_social();

        vcard.str_vcard += vcard.str_end;

        $('textarea[name="vcard"]').val(vcard.str_vcard);

        $('#qr').attr('src',vcard.goog_chart+vcard.str_vcard.replace(/\n/g,'%0A'));

        vcard.str_vcard = vcard.str_start;
    }
};

 //input click function
 $(function(){
  $('input[name="submit"]').click(vcard.save);
 });


</script>
```